# Why is Kotlin's generateSequence returning one too many items in the example below?

Tags: kotlin, sequence

I'm calculating the projection of instants in time based on a cron expression and returning them as a `Sequence`.  Here's the class:

```kotlin
// (package omitted)

import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

class Recurrence(val cronExpression: String) {
    private val cron = CronExpression.parse(cronExpression)

    fun instants(
        fromInclusive: LocalDate = LocalDate.now(),
        toExclusive: LocalDate = fromInclusive.plusMonths(1)
    ): Sequence<LocalDateTime> = instants(fromInclusive.atStartOfDay(), toExclusive.atStartOfDay())

    fun instants(
        fromInclusive: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
        toExclusive: LocalDateTime = fromInclusive.plusMonths(1)
    ): Sequence<LocalDateTime> {
        return generateSequence(cron.next(fromInclusive.minusNanos(1))) {
            if (it.isBefore(toExclusive)) {
                cron.next(it)
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The following test fails because the first assertion is false:  the returned list has one extra, unexpected element at the end.

```kotlin
// (package omitted)

import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.Month
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class RecurrenceTest {
    @Test
    fun testInstants() {
        val r = Recurrence("@daily")
        val from = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.JANUARY, 1)
        val forDays = 31
        val instants = r.instants(from, from.plusDays(forDays.toLong())).toList()
        assertEquals(forDays, instants.size)
        (1..forDays).forEach {
            assertEquals(from.plusDays(it.toLong() - 1).atStartOfDay(), instants[it - 1])
        }
    }
}
```

If I reimplement by building an `ArrayList` instead, it works as expected:

```
// new collection-based methods in Recurrence
    fun instantsList(
        fromInclusive: LocalDate = LocalDate.now(),
        toExclusive: LocalDate = fromInclusive.plusMonths(1)
    ): List<LocalDateTime> = instantsList(fromInclusive.atStartOfDay(), toExclusive.atStartOfDay())

    fun instantsList(
        fromInclusive: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
        toExclusive: LocalDateTime = fromInclusive.plusMonths(1)
    ): List<LocalDateTime> {
        val list = arrayListOf<LocalDateTime>()
        var it = cron.next(fromInclusive.minusNanos(1))
        while (it !== null) {
            if (it.isBefore(toExclusive)) {
                list.add(it)
                it = cron.next(it)
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        return list
    }
```

The one line to change in the test is to use the new method:

```kotlin
val instants = r.instantsList(from, from.plusDays(forDays.toLong()))
```

Why is the sequence-based implementation returning me one more element than the list-based one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, in list implementation you check if `it.isBefore(toExclusive)` and only then you add it to the list. In sequence implementation you do the same check `it.isBefore(toExclusive)` and then you add **next** item to the sequence.

Similar with the first item. In list implementation you check if `cron.next(fromInclusive.minusNanos(1))` meets the requirement. In sequence implementation you always add it.

Comment: You spotted it.  Correct sequence implementation is `    fun instants(
        fromInclusive: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
        toExclusive: LocalDateTime = fromInclusive.plusMonths(1)
    ): Sequence<LocalDateTime> {
        val seed = cron.next(fromInclusive.minusNanos(1))

        return generateSequence(seed) {
            val next = cron.next(it)

            if (next.isBefore(toExclusive)) {
                next
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
    }
`

Comment: OMG no code formatting in comments.  Ugh.  I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @broot -- you spotted the issue.  Just took another set of eyeballs.  Correct sequence implementation is

```kotlin
    fun instants(
        fromInclusive: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
        toExclusive: LocalDateTime = fromInclusive.plusMonths(1)
    ): Sequence<LocalDateTime> {
        val seed = cron.next(fromInclusive.minusNanos(1))

        return generateSequence(seed) {
            val next = cron.next(it)

            if (next.isBefore(toExclusive)) {
                next
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that this solution still differs from the list implementation, because `seed` is not checked before adding it to the sequence. I don't know if this check is required or not. You can also make the body of `generateSequence()` much shorter: `cron.next(it).takeIf { it.isBefore(toExclusive) }`.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you intentionally chose to use `generateSequence()` which requires to provide a `nextFunction` or you just didn't notice there are other ways to create a sequence. If you are satisfied with your list implementation, then it can be used almost 1:1 to create a sequence as well. Just use `sequence { }` instead of `generateSequence { }` and replace `list.add()` with `yield()`.